# Is there a way to use variables within the sheet as parameters in the VBA command Shell() for Powershell?

Tags: vba, shell, powershell

My current macro should execute a Powershell script that's been generated within an Excel Workbook, in my case let's say I generated SomeScript.ps1 in my Documents folder.

The macro should refer to Sheet1 within the workbook and obtain a user inputted file location (e.g. C:\Users\JohnDoe\Documents\SomeScript.ps1).

From there I would like to execute that script using the cell containing the file location.
How would I go about doing that?

I've tried assigning the file location to PSLocation and then calling it within the Shell() function.

```vb
Sub Button_Click()

   PSLocation = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2).Value + "SomeScript.ps1"

   Call Shell("powershell -noexit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file ""PSLocation""")

End Sub
```

I would like the script to run as it works if I assign it a local file however  Powershell script crashes upon opening if I use PSLocation.

Comment: Use the `&` string contatenation operator. You want `PSLocation` to be understood as a variable reference, not some string literal.`Shell "powershell -noexit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file """ & PSLocation & """`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to pass the arguments from VBA to a powershell command. The `path` parameter could be read from a worksheet as well:

`path = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2).Value + "SomeScript.ps1"`

```
Sub OpenPath()    
    Dim path As String: path = "C:\Desktop\Extraction_Files\"
    Shell "powershell -noexit explorer.exe " & path, vbNormalFocus    
End Sub
```